# How to show specific div class on order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm getting some data using loop to HTML DIVs. There can have many more data. Data showing something like below code.There have two classes for DIVs (`test one` and `test two` )
How to show all of "test one" data first and then "test two" data.How can i do this with **`javascript`** or **`Jquery`**?

**[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1m0c2qex/1/)**.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="test one">1</div>
   <div class="test one">1</div>
   <div class="test two">2</div>
   <div class="test one">1</div>
   <div class="test two">2</div>
   <div class="test one">1</div>
   <div class="test two">2</div>
   <div class="test two">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"How to show all of "test one" data first and then "test two" data."*. Clarify this.

Comment: Show data based on what?? and class name can't have space in your case...

Comment: test one = 1
test two = 2,
Current display order is like this 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2
i want to show 1111 first..

Comment: he means sorting it using CSS.. like showing all divs with .one and then showing all . two - as far as I know that is not possible without a programming or scrpting langauge i.e JavaScript in this case

Comment: Like this? 
https://jsfiddle.net/1m0c2qex/2/

Comment: @sanbg most answers given only work for one & two, if three is generated it wont work.

Comment: Are you capable of changing the class names? i.e. to data-1, data-2, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the jQuery library that could be done by cloning the container then loop through the cloned instance and get the `.one` element first then the `.two` ones and append them to the original container after clearing it using `$('.container').html('');` ,check the working snippet below.

Hope this will helps you.

```js
var container = $('.container').clone();

$('.container').html('');

container.find('.one').each(function() {
  $('.container').append($(this)[0].outerHTML);
})

container.find('.two').each(function() {
  $('.container').append($(this)[0].outerHTML);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As Hash already pointed out, this will only work for two classes, one and two. If you add three and four they will simply be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

This can be achieved using the `order` property of flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.test.two {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: _How can i do this with javascript or Jquery?_ the OP didn't ask for CSS solution..

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Probably because he was not aware of a CSS solution. Going CSS if possible is always a good idea. Not sure if the CSS solution is versatile enough in this case, though.

Comment: @BramVanroy as i mentioned only will work for one and two

Comment: @Hash, you are correct. The example I've given will only work for two items. If the number of divs is very long then using js might be easier. If not, the CSS can easily be extended.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki OP tagged the question CSS, I assumed he was open to alternatives

Answer (score 2):

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var items = $('.container .test').get();
      console.log(items);
      items.sort(function(a,b){
          var keyA = $(a).text();
          var keyB = $(b).text();

          if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
          if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
          return 0;
      });
      var container = $('.container');
      $.each(items, function(i, div){
          container.append(div);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="test one">1</div>
    <div class="test one">1</div>
    <div class="test two">2</div>
    <div class="test one">1</div>
    <div class="test two">2</div>
    <div class="test one">1</div>
    <div class="test two">2</div>
    <div class="test two">2</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of an simple [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on an array which contains the elements and replace the innerhtml of the `.container` element.

```js
var elements = $('.container').children();
elements.sort(function(a,b){
 return a.className > b.className;
});
$('.container').html(elements);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
  <div class="test one">1</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
  <div class="test two">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is only working for one and two, if you add i.e. three and four, this does not work (showing 4 as first, then one, three then two), due to the comparison of class names